# How would you solve this query?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

Let's say this is your database:

```
   A    B           C 
  157  szept-01   3000 
  157  okt-01     -312
```

I tried this: (ofc, i get a not a group by warning, because C isn't grouped by)
But i would like to get the value of C in my query, how could i solve it?

```
    Select A, MIN(B), C
    FROM DB
    GROUP BY A;
```

When i use this (I get every value of C for every B, but i ONLY want value C for the minimal B)

```
    Select A, MIN(B), C
    FROM DB
    GROUP BY A, C;
```

This is my purpose:

```
    A    B          C
   157  szept-01   3000
```

EDIT:
I dont see it duplicate, the other is not solved perfectly imho. (There are tons of updates, and i dont see the exact answer)

Comment: Just replace max with min in the duplicate topic.

Comment: The accepted answer in that indicated thread offers two different solutions which produce the same (desired) result. Have you tried applying either approach to your situation?